# Is it possible to create "anchor points" for an image, in another image?

Tags: javascript, css

I'll preface this question by asserting that I'm no "Web Guy".  I have little to no experience programming in JavaScript, or any other Web-based programming technology aside from XML and some related XSLT; go easy on me!

What I suppose I'm trying to create is something akin to an imagemap: I would like to place an image on a webpage then, based on information I've received back from a hardware chassis, populate the various "hardware slots" in the image of the chassis with an image of the piece of hardware that is in that location.

I'd like to create these points and have them relative to the image, not the browser window, so that I could create the image of the chassis anywhere and still place the images of the cards over their appropriate slots.

Is there a mechanism for using `vars` to hold the offsets, and then placing the other images, using those `var` offsets relative to the chassis image?  Is there a different way to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with ThiefMaster, and a sketch for some markup would be something like this.

```
<div class="chassi">
    <div id="slot1" class="slot"></div>
    <div id="slot2" class="slot"></div>
    // more slots if needed 
</div>

<style>
    .chassi
    {
         position: relative;
         background: url(/path/to/your/image.png);
    }
    .slot
    {
         position:absolute;
    }
    #slot1
    {
         left: 20px;
         top: 20px;
    }
    #slot2
    {
         left: 20px;
         top: 60px;
    }

</style>
```

Then using javascript to load the slot data, and adding images to the "slot"-divs.

Comment: No problem, just let me know if you have any follow up questions. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could simply put them at the correct positions using CSS absolute/relative positioning.

Another solution would be using a `<canvas>` to actually draw an image consisting of multiple other images.

Comment: This looks like precisely what I need to look into.  Like I said, my ignorance of web programming shows almost immediately when I dig into this stuff.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Its called `image mapping` and you can read about it [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml)

Comment: Can you place another image in an image map's "area"? I see the "href" attributes, but would it take an image src?

Comment: This is not correct. An image map is one image with several clickable areas. The poster wants to fit several images into one.